# wp 7 disable scrolling in LongListSelector

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml

I have a LongListSelector on my wp7 page. Is it possible to disable scrolling on LongListSelector?

Comment: have you looked at this article?

http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/wp7-longlistselector-in-depth--part2-data-binding-scenarios

Comment: I thought the page might have the information you were looking for. Anyways you can try this `extract the child scrollviewer from the listSelector and disable its scrolling thereby disabling the overall scrolling`